# Next Js 14 css gone after removing cookies from browser

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I had deleted all the cookies for localhost300 by going to applications tab in chrome , now my next js app is looking very ugly

I was deleting the token stored for authentication but in fun i deletd some cookies with name i guess server now this had happened